# trigger R actionbutton event when session opens

Tags: r, shiny

In a Shiny app, I am trying to have an eventReactive triggered either with an actionbutton OR when the session opens.
I've tryed the below code using `session$clientData` but it doesn't work.
Also tried to play with `toggleModal` from `shinyBS` but still no chance. Any help much appreciated. Thanks!

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("go", "Go"),
  numericInput("n", "n", 50),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(session, input, output) {

  randomVals <- eventReactive({input$go
  session$clientData}, {
    runif(input$n)
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    hist(randomVals())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: "It doesn't work." You should be as clear as possible about failure modes.

Answer (score 2):

Actually figured this out. On my question above, I tried to simplified my code, and doing so actually fixed the issue...

```
randomVals <- eventReactive({input$go
  session$clientData}
```

works as expected (i.e. you get a chart when opening the session even without clicking on go), while

```
randomVals <- eventReactive({session$clientData
  input$go}
```

doesn't work (i.e you need to click on go to get your first chart
So I guess the order in the event {} matters, which I didn't know